# Heatmap in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I made a heat map from a table in GGPLOT2. Below you can see my code.

```
library(ggplot2)
    TestData1<-structure(list(Countries = c("AL", "CA", "DE", "ES", "MA", "EL", 
                                            "AL", "CA", "DE", "ES", "MA", "EL", "AL", "CA", "DE", "ES", "MA", 
                                            "EL"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Total", 
                                                                                                                              "Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), value = c(-3.06, -4.41, 
                                                                                                                                                                              6.97, -2.74, 5.54, -1.31, -2.47, -3.45, 4.11, -3.06, 4.82, -1.73, 
                                                                                                                                                                              -3.95, -5.76, 8.74, -1.87, 6.37, -0.79)), row.names = c(NA, -18L
                                                                                                                                                                              ), class = "data.frame")
    
    
    ggplot(TestData1, aes(x = Countries, y = factor(variable, levels = rev(levels(factor(variable)))))) +
      
      #make heatmap with geom_tile based on the total number of devices
      geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
      
      #add the total number of devices to each tile
      geom_text(aes(label = value), color = "white") + 
      #some formatting to make things easier to read
      scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
      scale_fill_gradient(high = "#132B43", low = "#56B1F7") +
      theme(legend.position = "none", 
            panel.grid = element_blank(), 
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
            axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
      labs(y = " ")
```

This code produces a heat map as the map below

[image]

Now I want to produce the same chart but in Plotly. I can make it very easily with ggplotly command, but I am not satisfied with the appearance because the converted object is not the same. For example, hovering with the mouse give the names of the factors instead of values, the title is in bold etc.

So can anybody create this heat map but in Plotly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `type='heatmap'` with `add_annotations` to add the y variable. Make sure `showarrow = FALSE` like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

TestData1 %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Countries, y = ~variable, z = ~value, type = "heatmap", colors = c("#56B1F7", "#132B43")) %>%
  add_annotations(text = ~value, x = ~Countries, y = ~variable, showarrow = FALSE, font = list(color = "white")) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"), 
         yaxis = list(title = ""), 
         showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  hide_colorbar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>